# Set Item in CheckedListBox selected, if it is existend in a List

Tags: c#, winforms, datasource, checkedlistbox

I have a CheckedListBox. As the DataSource I use a BindingList of my own Class  `var dataSource3 = new BindingList<Modells.Person>();`.

Afterwards I sort them alphapetical.

```
var sorteddataSource3 = new BindingList<Modells.Person>(dataSource3.OrderBy(x => x.lastname).ToList());
```

And bind them.

```
clbPerson3.DataSource = sorteddataSource3;
clbPerson3.DisplayMember = "lastname";
clbPerson3.ValueMember = "idPerson";
```

My own Class is structured like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int idPerson { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public string phonenumber { get; set; }
    public string mailadress { get; set; }
    public int idCompany { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have an other List of "Persons", which I get from a RestRequest: `IRestResponse<List<Modells.Person>> selectedPersons = client.Execute<List<Modells.Person>>(request);`

And now the task is to set the persons from the `selectedPersons` checked in the CheckedListBox `sorteddataSource3`.

My Solution at this point in time is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < selectedPersons.Data.Count; i++)
{
    if (selectedPersons.Data[i].idCompany.Equals(comboBox3.SelectedValue))
    {
        int index3 = clbPerson3.Items.IndexOf(selectedPersons.Data[i].idPerson);
        clbPerson3.SetItemChecked(index3, true);
    }
}
```

First I check if the person is displayed in the CheckedListBox.
Afterwards I try to get the Index of the person. And here is the mistake I have. `index3` is always `-1`.

I am looking for an Solution to set Items checked in a CheckedListBox.

Comment: Your question seems to mix up __selecting__ and __checking__.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that the objects in `selectedPersons` may have identical values as the objects in `sorteddataSource3` but the objects them self are not the same. You need to implement some sort of comparison. A very simple approach would be to select the items from `sorteddataSource3` that also appear in `selectedPersons` (at least objects with same values) and then iterate over those (For this example I assume, that idPerson is the primary key):

```
var selectList = sorteddataSource3.Where(s => selectedPersons.Data.Any(p => p.idPerson == s.idPerson)).ToList();

foreach(Person person in selectList)
{
    int index3 = clbPerson3.Items.IndexOf(person);
    clbPerson3.SetItemChecked(index3, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `clbPerson3.Items` is strongly typed, every item is of type `Person` and you are looking for number in this collection, which is obviously never found. So your lookup function should be a little bit different, e.g.:

```
int index3 = clbPerson3.Items.IndexOf(dataSource3.Where(p => p.idPerson == selectedPersons.Data[i].idPerson).Single());
```